# Assert that collection "Contains at least one non-null element"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertions, hamcrest

I want to verify that a collection contains at least one non-null element. I have tried `is(not(empty()))`, however this passes in the test below.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.empty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

public class SandBoxTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldTestThis() {
        Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        collection.add(null);

        assertThat(collection, is(not(empty())));
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant/simple way to do this?

**Things That Don't Work**

```
@Test
public void should(){
    Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList();
    collection.add("gfas");
    collection.add("asda");
    assertThat(collection, contains(notNullValue()));
}

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable containing [not null]
     but: Not matched: "asda"
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

...
    
assertThat(collection, hasItem(notNullValue(Integer.class)));
```

Unfortunately, there is a [bug in Java 1.6](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7034548) that means you might have to split it onto 2 lines as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=143) if you are using 1.6:

```
Matcher<Iterable<? super String>> matcher = hasItem(notNullValue(Integer.class));
assertThat(collection, matcher);
```

---

**EDIT** Here is the [FEST Assert](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x) example you asked for:

```
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;
...
assertThat(collection).doesNotContainNull();
```

FEST requires only a single static import so you get full IDE auto completion.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem and solved it as follows.

The basic idea is that if the collection has only `null` elements, converted to a set it will contain just one element and it will be `null`. If not so, then the collection contains at least one non-null element.

I wrote a matcher, and tried it with this test:

```
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Factory;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static personal.CollectionOfNullsMatcher.collectionOfNulls;


public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void should_check_collection_for_non_null_values() {
        Collection<String> testedCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
        testedCollection.add(null);

        assertThat(testedCollection, is(collectionOfNulls()));

        testedCollection.add("any");

        assertThat(testedCollection, is(not(collectionOfNulls())));
    }
}

class CollectionOfNullsMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Collection> {

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final Collection collection) {
        Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(collection);
        return (set.size() == 1) && (set.toArray()[0] == null);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {
        description.appendText("collection of nulls");
    }

    @Factory
    public static <T> Matcher<Collection> collectionOfNulls() {
        return new CollectionOfNullsMatcher();
    }
}
```

Of course, in a real project, the matcher should be placed together with its brothers :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice, a reusable matcher.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, chaining `Matcher` instances. You just need the `hasItem` matcher (like I've suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720233/hamcrest-matchers-contains-matcher-not-working)) instead of `contains`.

> Creates a matcher for `Iterable`s that only matches when a single pass
> over the examined `Iterable` yields **at least one item that is matched by
> the specified `itemMatcher`**. Whilst matching, the traversal of the
> examined `Iterable` will stop as soon as a matching item is found.

For example,

```
Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
collection.add(null);

assertThat(collection, hasItem(is(not(nullValue()))));
```

will fail with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing is not null
     but: was null
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
    at com.example.ExampleTest.should(ExampleTest.java:21)
    at [...]
```

whereas

```
Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
collection.add(null);
collection.add("hey");
collection.add(null);

assertThat(collection, hasItem(is(not(nullValue()))));
// or shortened
assertThat(collection, hasItem(notNullValue()));
```

will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
public void shouldTestThis() {
        Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        collection.add(null);
        collection.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); // remove all "null" elements from collection
        assertThat(collection, is(not(empty())));
    }
```

As ajb notices, if you want to left your array unmodified, you should use an iterator and check each element until the end of the collection or a non null one.

Comment: The point is to check if it has `null` elements. You shouldn't remove them.

Comment: The point is "to verify that a collection contains at least one non-null element."

Comment: You could make this work without removing the `null` elements by making a copy of the collection (declare a temporary collection `c` and use `c.addAll`).  But for that amount of work, you may as well just use an iterator.

Comment: I will probably use this approach, but this would not work if the collection was immutable

Comment: If the collection was immutable, you would have to use an iterator as `@ajb` notices