# are `Matchers.hasItem` and `Matchers.contains` the same?

Tags: java, matcher, hamcrest

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720548/1065869)

about the difference between:

```
Matchers.hasItem(..)

Assert.assertThat(items, Matchers.hasItem(Matchers.hasToString("c")));
which states
```

and

```
Matchers.contains
```

But I still don't get the difference. They both look for one predicate satisfaction. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are almost the same, but `Matchers.hasItem` as said

> will stop as soon as a matching item is found

Then `Matchers.contains`

> the examined iterable must only yield one item

The difference is that first one checks whether there is at least one item (may be two or more), but the second one checks that there is exactly one item (only one, no more).

Comment: thanks, then how can I check if at least one item satisfies 2 matchers for example? because contains is the only one to get few matchers

Answer (score 1):

With `hasItem`, the iterable needs to have at least one item which matches the parameter matcher. In addition, it can have more items (matching or not), in any order. (The matcher is tried on each element until one of them matches, the rest is ignored.)

With `contains`, the iterable needs to have exactly the item (or items) which are matched by the parameter (or parameters), in the same order, and no others. (I.e. the first item needs to match the first parameter matcher, the second item the second parameter matcher, ... and the last item the last parameter matcher. Each matcher is tried on just one element.)
With just one parameter, this means the iterable needs to have exactly one element.

Comment: thanks, then how can I check if at least one item satisfies 2 matchers for example? because contains is the only one to get few matchers

Comment: @EladBenda2 if I understand right (you want to make sure that there is an item which is matched by both matchers), have a look at `Matchers.both(matcher1).and(matcher2)`.